# can't connect django rest api with flutter and it always show connect refused

Tags: flutter, rest, django-rest-framework, flutter-dependencies, flutter-http

```
async{
     try {
           var url = Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/todoget/");
           var response = await http.get(url,);
           print(response.statusCode.toString());
         }
      catch (e)   
      {
        print(e.toString());
      }
```

I want to connect Django API to flutter using the flutter dependency `http`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Here are some guidelines that will help you get quicker / more focused responses in the future https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask